# sparksql output dataframe has no records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark sql code

```
object MyTest extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GTPCP KPIs")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val hContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    val outputDF = hContext.sql("Select field1, field2 from prddb.cust_data")
      println("records selected: " + outputDF.count() + "\n")
      outputDF.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("devdb.vs_test")
      //outputDF.show()
}
```

The problem is that if i run the query

```
Select field1, field2 from prddb.cust_data
```

in hive it gives me around 1.5 million records.

However, through spark sql I am not getting any output in devdb.vs_test table
The println statement prints 0.

I am using spark 1.5.0

Any help here will be appreciated!!

Comment: that means that your spark is not able to connect to your hive table. Are you getting any error while running your first statement

Comment: No!! I don't see any error in logs

Comment: Did you try setting below configuration    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("jobName")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);

Comment: updated the full code

Comment: can you try doing -  val df = hContext.table("prddb.tblname").select("field1,"field2"); and df.show. Can you run this on spark-shell and check

Comment: thats the shitty part, i dont have access to spark-shell. i am firing jobs through oozie

Comment: No effect!!Still No output

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like your spark-session doesn't have hive connectivity to it.

You need to link hive-site.xml with spark conf or copy hive-site.xml into spark conf directory. Spark is not able to find your hive metastore (derby database which is by default), so for that we have to link hive-conf to spark conf direcrtory.

Finally, to connect Spark SQL to an existing Hive installation, you must copy your hive-site.xml file to Spark’s configuration directory ($SPARK_HOME/conf). If you don’t have an existing Hive installation, Spark SQL will still run.

Sudo to root user and then copy hive-site to spark conf directory.

```
sudo -u root 
cp /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf
```

Comment: Sorry I have the hive-site.xml in my workflow itself. The issue was that prddb.cust_data table permission were fine but the underlying HDFS permissions were 700 which did not allow me spark to read file. After the underlying permissions on HDFS were fixed to 750, the issue was resolved.